# Xamarin ListView update cell display

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, cell

I change the size of cells using slider, but Cells of listView are not updating
how to do it? What else is missing?

Adding new items is also not displayed, but if you check them with a debugger, there are such items in the list

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lstView.RowHeight = (int)e.NewValue;
}
```

Full code of this work:

```
public class RootPage : ContentPage
    {
        ListView listView;
        public RootPage ()
        {
            listView = new ListView() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand };
            listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyCustomCell));
            listView.ItemsSource = new CustomText[] { new CustomText("asd", "bsd"), new CustomText("abra", "kadabra") };
            listView.HasUnevenRows = true;
            var slider = new Slider() {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                Maximum = 300,
                Minimum = 100
            };
            slider.ValueChanged += Slider_ValueChanged;
            Content = new StackLayout {
                Spacing = 20,
                Children = {
                    listView,
                    slider
                }
            };
        }

        private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView.RowHeight = (int)e.NewValue;
        }
    }



public class CustomText
    {
        public string T1 { get; set; }
        public string T2 { get; set; }
        public CustomText(string t1, string t2)
        {
            T1 = t1;
            T2 = t2;
        }
    }
    public class MyCustomCell : ViewCell
    {
        public MyCustomCell()
        {
            var label1 = new Label();
            var label2 = new Label();

            label1.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("T1"));
            label2.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("T2"));

            var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout()
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Olive,
                Children = {
                    label1,
                    label2
                }
            };

            View = horizontalLayout;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to change `RowHeight` on your MainThread: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { code here });`

Comment: @DennisSchröer i'm tryed `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { listView.RowHeight = (int)e.NewValue; });`, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
            listView.HasUnevenRows = true;
```

Exactly means that changing RowHeight of the list view has no effect as the height is defined for each row, not for the list view.